# How do I fix my navbar display over divs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on a personal project in React and I followed a tutorial to develop a nav side-bar.

It was working well till i added some sort of cards to the homepage. Now the divs which are reprenseting the cards are displayed over the navbar instead over it.

I will attach some photos also the code for the Navbar, the css for it and the Cards code and css as well.

[The nav bar problem photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZE6W.jpg)

Navbar js

```
import * as FaIcons from "react-icons/fa";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { SidebarData } from "./SidebarData";
import "./Navbar.css";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "#fff" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
            <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className="navbar-toggle">
              <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
                <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose />
              </Link>
            </li>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
                    {item.icon}
                    <span>{item.title}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Navbar CSS

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #9f4650;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-bars {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: none;
}

.nav-menu {
  background-color: #9f4650;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  transition: 850ms;
}

.nav-menu.active {
  left: 0;
  transition: 350ms;
}

.nav-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav-text a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-text-last a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 8.5rem;
}

.nav-text a:hover {
  background-color: #1a83ff;
}

.nav-menu-items {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #9f4650;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

span {
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

Cards JS

```
import React from "react";
import "./Cards.css";

function Cards() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="cards-wrapper">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-image"></div>
          <div className="card-title">
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="card-1">
          <div className="card-image"></div>
          <div className="card-title-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-image"></div>
          <div className="card-title"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="card-1">
          <div className="card-image"></div>
          <div className="card-title-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-image"></div>
          <div className="card-title"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Cards;
```

Cards CSS

```
.cards-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-top: 6rem;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.card-1 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Could you add a code snippet? https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Yes, I will try but I'm not sure i will succeed.

Comment: Actually I tried but I can't import the libraries I used in react, sorry, but i am a noob.

Comment: have you tried to remove position absolute  if it still overlap ?

Comment: Yeah, first it was on relative, then i changed it to absolute but same result tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding extra properties in your classes

```
 .navbar {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 999;
      left: 0;
      top: 0
      background-color: #9f4650;
      height: 80px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: center;
    }
```